# Update php variable and select option on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php variable

`$cur_selection='one';`

which I currently have getting a default value of 'one' as shown above.

I have a drop down select called courses and a button which I would like by default to start off with the first Option.

```
<select id='courses'>
<option value='one'>Select Option</option>
<option value='two'>two</option>
<option value='three'>three</option>
</select>

<button onclick="RefreshpageAndChangeVariableandSelector()">Click Me!</button>
```

as you can see the list is populated with options that have values.

Upon selecting an option other than the default option then clicking the button I wish to have to page refresh updating the value of $cur_selection to be the value of the chosen option while also changing the selection in the `courses` drop down menu to what was chosen before clicking.

However I am clueless what to put into the `RefreshpageAndChangeVariableandSelector()` to do what I need it to do

For this solution I am not looking to use AJAX but to refresh to page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real answer using refresh (I can think of) involves query parameters.  This will involve some pseudo code, but it should get you started.  If you still have questions, comment and I can update my answer :)

**Javascript**

```
function RefreshpageAndChangeVariableandSelector(value)
{
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '?selected=' + value;
    // Note, this needs more logic (in case the page is already ?selected=one)
}
```

**PHP**

```
$default_value = 'one';
$cur_selection = !empty($_GET['selected']) ? $_GET['selected'] : $default_value;
```

The Javascript function will take a value (or you can write logic to determine the value) and encode it with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  Then it will append it as the query parameter `selected`.  This part needs more logic to make sure we don't append a `?` when its already there or send 2 different values for `selected`.  If you are lost here, let me know and I'll help.  By updating the `window.location.href`, Javascript will make a new `GET` request with the browser (not technically a refresh).

The PHP uses a [shorthand conditional](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) to make sure that `$_GET['selected']` isn't [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty).  This is necessary because you will get an exception if you just look for `$_GET['selected']` when it isn't sent.  If it is empty, we fallback to a default value.

---

**Update**

```
$default_value = 'one';

// This...
$cur_selection = !empty($_GET['selected']) ? $_GET['selected'] : $default_value;

// Is the same as...
if(!empty($_GET['selected'])) {
    $cur_selection = $_GET['selected'];
} else {
    $cur_selection = $default_value;
}

// And can also work like...
$cur_selection = $default_value;
if(!empty($_GET['selected'])) {
    $cur_selection = $_GET['selected'];
}
```

Comment: Ok, i thought might end up dealing with query parameters. I am just not as versed in php which is why the setting the default is slightly confusing but I can make sense of that. I will give that a shot and see where I end up with it. thanks

Comment: @John, I updated my answer and elaborated on the conditional used for the default value.  You are kind of *forced* to use query parameters.  You can't pass any special data to the server with a "refresh" since that is a simple `GET` request (not `POST`, etc).  The server can't read anchor tags (`#top`) or anything, so it has to resort to the URL or the query parameters.  Since the URL will serve up the same content, that kind of leaves us with the query parameter.  Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Yes your answer definitely helps and I can figure out the query parameter logic that shouldnt be too bad.  Wouldnt I then have to pass a parameter `value` whenenver using that js function? Can I use a js or php variable?

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't really sure where you *did* get the value from.  I assume you would actually find it within the function (rather than passing it to the function).  If you are wanting the value of your select, you could do this in Javascript: `var value = document.getElementById('courses').value;`.

Comment: Fair enough i didn't really specify. but ok Im familiar with jquery that actually seems like the solution I was heading towards more or less.  I suppose to use a php variable this is where ajax would have come into play?

Comment: It really depends on *what* your end goal is.  The purpose of AJAX is to communicate with the server while not reloading the page.  For instance, you could POST data (a comment form) to a database without loading a new page or you could GET more results (pagination) from a database without loading a new page.  If you want to modify the look of the page, you may just be able to do this with jQuery.  If you really want to refresh the page, send a new variable to the server, and get the new contents...this is best done with the method we have now (I can't really think of a use case, though).

Comment: Right now there is no real end result as it is mostly theoretical but yes I eventually do wish to update a sql query to a database with that selection.  I appreciate the help

Comment: Probably would make most sense to use an AJAX call (look at [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). You never really want to *modify* a database with a plain `GET` request, so instead of just reloading a page you can use AJAX to `POST`. I'd make a new question if you get confused with that.

Comment: Yeah I'm still testing the waters just seeing what each solution entails.  I might ask that one tomorrow :)